# Python Plotly: Plotting Active Users against multiple timezone

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a dataset like this:

```
>>> data.iloc[5:29]
                    JST                  EST                  UTC  ACTIVE_USER 
5   2021-07-17 00:00:00  2021-07-16 11:00:00  2021-07-16 15:00:00         9339 
6   2021-07-17 01:00:00  2021-07-16 12:00:00  2021-07-16 16:00:00         9499 
7   2021-07-17 02:00:00  2021-07-16 13:00:00  2021-07-16 17:00:00        13652 
8   2021-07-17 03:00:00  2021-07-16 14:00:00  2021-07-16 18:00:00        11897 
9   2021-07-17 04:00:00  2021-07-16 15:00:00  2021-07-16 19:00:00        11961 
10  2021-07-17 05:00:00  2021-07-16 16:00:00  2021-07-16 20:00:00        12192 
11  2021-07-17 06:00:00  2021-07-16 17:00:00  2021-07-16 21:00:00        12339 
12  2021-07-17 07:00:00  2021-07-16 18:00:00  2021-07-16 22:00:00        12174 
13  2021-07-17 08:00:00  2021-07-16 19:00:00  2021-07-16 23:00:00        11627 
14  2021-07-17 09:00:00  2021-07-16 20:00:00  2021-07-17 00:00:00        11607 
15  2021-07-17 10:00:00  2021-07-16 21:00:00  2021-07-17 01:00:00        11120 
16  2021-07-17 11:00:00  2021-07-16 22:00:00  2021-07-17 02:00:00        11600 
17  2021-07-17 12:00:00  2021-07-16 23:00:00  2021-07-17 03:00:00         9739 
18  2021-07-17 13:00:00  2021-07-17 00:00:00  2021-07-17 04:00:00        10269 
19  2021-07-17 14:00:00  2021-07-17 01:00:00  2021-07-17 05:00:00        10779 
20  2021-07-17 15:00:00  2021-07-17 02:00:00  2021-07-17 06:00:00        11339 
21  2021-07-17 16:00:00  2021-07-17 03:00:00  2021-07-17 07:00:00        10920 
22  2021-07-17 17:00:00  2021-07-17 04:00:00  2021-07-17 08:00:00        11631 
23  2021-07-17 18:00:00  2021-07-17 05:00:00  2021-07-17 09:00:00        11316 
24  2021-07-17 19:00:00  2021-07-17 06:00:00  2021-07-17 10:00:00        11464 
25  2021-07-17 20:00:00  2021-07-17 07:00:00  2021-07-17 11:00:00        11825 
26  2021-07-17 21:00:00  2021-07-17 08:00:00  2021-07-17 12:00:00        12319 
27  2021-07-17 22:00:00  2021-07-17 09:00:00  2021-07-17 13:00:00        11474 
28  2021-07-17 23:00:00  2021-07-17 10:00:00  2021-07-17 14:00:00        13952
```

My goal is to visualize and analyze the peak hours/ which zone(s) the users are mainly based on.

With this simple code I could have a nice bar chart:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("proc.csv")

fig = px.bar(data.iloc[5:29], x='JST', y='ACTIVE_USER')

fig.write_html('tmp.html', auto_open=False)
```

[image]

But it only works for a single time zone. What I expected is something similar to this:

[image]

I have checked the [multiple axis function](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/) but it does not look like the thing I wanted.

Is there a way to achieve this with Plotly? Also suggestion with other libraries is also welcomed if there a simple way for that.

Comment: The images aren't visible make sure you have uploaded them correctly https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to propose a subplot that combines a bar chart and a table. The first graph is used as a bar chart for JST, and the second table has cells with data extracted only for EST and UTC times. We adopted the subplot because the x-axis can be shared. However, it is not clear if it satisfies all the requirements since it only expresses the time. One thing to note is that text annotations were not possible in the table, so I used the first graph criteria to determine the text placement.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=1,
    shared_xaxes=True,
    vertical_spacing=0.08,
    specs=[[{"type": "bar"}],
           [{"type": "table"}]
          ]
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df['JST'],
        y=df["ACTIVE_USER"],
        name='JST'
    ),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=np.arange(0,24,1),
            fill_color='royalblue',
            font=dict(color='white', size=10),
            align="center"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=[[x[0][11:13], x[1][11:13]] for x in df[['EST','UTC']].values],
            align="left")
    ),
    row=2, col=1
)

fig.update_layout(
    height=800,
)
fig.add_annotation(x=-0.03, y=-0.35,
                   xref='x domain',
                   yref='y domain',
                   text='EST',
                   showarrow=False,
                   row=1, col=1)

fig.add_annotation(x=-0.03, y=-0.42,
                   xref='x domain',
                   yref='y domain',
                   text='UST',
                   showarrow=False,
                   row=1, col=1)
fig.show()
# fig.write_html('tmp.html', auto_open=False)
```

[image]

Comment: That's nice for a single day visualization, but I also want to visualize the growth of active users say from July till today by animation, day by day (in term of JST). With the subslot, is it possible that I only animate the barchart component inside it?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to animate only one graph in a subplot graph. I haven't tried it, but I think it is possible to animate the x-axis by adding a drop-down or a button to switch the x-axis.

Comment: Alright I will try digging deeper to see If I could do that. Worst case I can probably still loop the data by day and collect the frames. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

- approach of using multiple xaxis as documented here: https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-axes
- create a trace for each axis, traces will be on top of each other
- `yaxis={"domain": [0.2, 1]},` provide some space for the multiple xaxis

```
px.bar(df, x="JST", y="ACTIVE_USER").add_traces(
    px.bar(df, x="EST", y="ACTIVE_USER").update_traces(xaxis="x2").data
).update_layout(
    xaxis2={
        "title": {"text": "EST", "standoff": 0},
        "position": 0,
    },
    xaxis={"position": 0.2, "title": {"standoff": 0}},
    yaxis={"domain": [0.2, 1]},
    margin={"b": 0},
)
```

[image]